# Is using template tags to pull data a violation of separation of concerns?

Tags: django, separation-of-concerns

I'm wondering if the [django generic flatblocks app](https://github.com/bartTC/django-generic-flatblocks) is a violation of the separation of concerns principle.
For those of you who do not know the app, it is pulling data based on a slug or id and a model type.
For example:

```
{% gblock "about" for "cms.FlatPageWithsummary" into "about" %}
```

On one hand, it marks where the content should appear so it makes sense from the designer's point of view but on the other hand it shouldn't be the template's responsibility to fetch data.
What should I do? Should I pass it through the request context?
Now I am facing another situation where I need to pull my latest posts and display them.
Where's the line here?
Because again, the designer is able to mark and implement this feature only by using my supplied template tag, but on the other hand, I am fetching data from a template which seems kinda wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What if it is? These "principles" are there to make our lives as developers and users easier. If the easiest and cleanest way to do something breaks that principle, we should feel free to do so, as long as the quality of the code doesn't suffer. It's not like there's a moral reason to observe separation of concerns at all costs.

And, don't forget, there are other principles to follow as well. Accepting for the sake of argument that this does break separation of concerns, it still most definitely follows DRY. If those principles are in conflict, you should choose which one to follow.

Comment: There are other ways to solve the DRY problem if I won't use template tags. The question is, who's responsibility is it to fetch the data? The view's or the template's?

Answer (score 0):

`django.contrib.comments` too [fetches data from the DB in a templatetag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#comment-template-tags). If you want to make your apps reusable, then this is a common pattern.

Comment: With the new class based views it is easy to provide a mixin that adds the posts to the extra_context variable. You didn't answer my question though. Is this a violation of SoC?

Comment: i don't think so. It's a way to keep things simple

Comment: Even if it keeps thing simple, it still not a valid argument for or against for whether it violates SoC or not.